# Hash function for expression literals

Tags: hash, expression

My DSL consists of next operators `AND`,`OR`,`>`,`<`,`>=`,`<=`,`=`,`!=`,`&`
& denotes intersection.

In my system i need to keep track of every individual subexpression, e.g. There can be no duplicates expressions. I store a global hash map of `hash => node_ptr` to retrieve requested subexpression in the tree.

`(name = "John" OR age > 25) AND (interests & ["sport", "education"])`

consists of:

`name = "John"`, `age > 25`, `name = "John" OR age > 25`, `interests & ["sport", "education"]`, and the original one `(name = "John" OR age > 25) AND (interests & ["sport", "education"])`

In total 5 subexpressions which need to be hashed.
For predicates it's easy, i can just hash the literal (string form) of predicate, e.g.
`int <= hash("attr>=100")` or `int <= hash("attr&{'a','b','c'}")`.

But it's not going to work for complex expressions such as `P1 AND P2`, because `P1 AND P2` and `P2 AND P1` is actually the same.
The idea is to replace each `OR` operator with multiplication, and each `AND` operator with addition, e.g.
`(P1 OR P2) AND (P4 OR P3)` translates to `hash(P1) * hash(P2) + hash(P4) * hash(P3)`.
Integer overflow could be a possible problem.
Is there any good hash function for my purpose or perhaps a better way of doing what i'm trying to do?

Comment: If this is a DSL, why don't you hash its intermediate representation (e.g. AST)? Do you already have that and are wondering how to hash multiple things or compound things?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I don't see how it helps tho, can you provide some example? This DSL is used to define a set or rules, against which upcoming event will be matched (pub/sub). And yeah, i'm looking for good solution for hashing compound expressions regardless of the order of the subexpressions

Comment: Well, for example for order independent operators the execution node / IR-object could just store the operands as a frozenset. That provides an order independent hash out of the box.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have a global hash map, of `hash => node pointer`, in my system  can be no duplicate expressions. But i got your idea, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are creating some sort of a rule engine, where you have to store predefined rules, and as data flows in, fire the appropriate rules. To accomplish that, you have to know which calculations to perform each time a new piece of data arrives, and that is the purpose of the global hash map.

The problem that you encountered is due to the fact that two syntactically different logical formulae may be logically equivalent. For example, as you mentioned, `(P1 AND P2)` is equivalent to `(P2 AND P1)`, but there are many more possible equivalences, like `(P1 > a OR P1 = a)` and `(P1 >= a)`. The problem is mitigated by the fact that your DSL does not contain the `NOT` operator (otherwise many more logical equivalences would be possible), but that does not eliminate it completely.

One possibility is to drop the constraint that there can be no duplicate expressions. This will cause some redundant calculations, but it's probably the easiest route.

If you want to keep the expressions logically distinct, you have to express them in some canonical form. One possibility is to take the following steps:
First, narrow down your DSL to make less room for logically equivalent expressions. For example, if the DSL has the operators `=` and `>`, then `>=` is unnecessary (of course, you can preserve the redundant operators in the user interface to maintain a good user experience, but in your hash map you can translate these operators to more basic ones).
Second, you should choose a canonical form for the logical formulae. For example, DNF or CNF would be appropriate.
Third, to make the order of expressions in the representation unique, you can use the fact that you can calculate hash values for atomic expressions, and then order the expressions in the canonical representations in ascending hash value order, for example.

Maintaining the constraint of non-duplicate expressions comes at some cost, but the heavy computation occurs when a new rule is created, and not when new data arrive and the system has to fire events as quickly as possible.